# Excel - get the column number based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have headings separated onto different rows. Instead of having a heading that makes sense and is unique like "Litres of water dumped on Tuesday" I have:

> Litres of
>  water
>  dumped
>  on Tuesday

separated across 4 rows.

I want to know how much water was dumped on Tuesday and there are multiple columns that say each of "Litres of", "water", "dumped" and "on Tuesday".  Is there an excel function that will help me do this?  Do I need to go use macros?

Comment: I find this very confusing, this sounds like a strange use of excel. What do you mean "I want to know how much water was dumped on tuesday"? How are you trying to communicate this question to excel, via typing in a string? Are you just trying to find a column that has all of the words in it? If you could put up a more thorough example it may help.

Comment: The data comes from the output of a program, which is then loaded into excel.  Yes, it is a very strange use of excel.  I want it set up so that I can load the raw data into one sheet and have another sheet give me graphs and things from the data.  The trouble is that the columns are not going to be the same everytime so I have to find these headings to know which column has the data I want.  The "water dump" thing is just an example heading, there are thousands of rows of data below that heading I need to process.

Comment: I think you're going to have to show (or upload) a much larger set of example data for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need the entire header to be in a single cell, as opposed to split over four rows in four parts that have no useful meaning individually.

You can do this using Excel's `CONCATENATE` function or, equivalently, the more succint `&` operator. Example:

[image]

Now you have your unique header and you can do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying? I am assuming that the data is arranged as shown in the snapshot.

`=OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("Address",INDEX(A1:D4,MATCH(TRUE,COUNTIF(OFFSET(A1:D4,ROW(A1:D4)-CELL("Row",A1:D4),0,1),F1)>0,0),MATCH(F1,INDEX(A1:D4,MATCH(TRUE,COUNTIF(OFFSET(A1:D4,ROW(A1:D4)-CELL("Row",A1:D4),0,1),F1)>0,0),0),0)))),1,0)`

This is an array formula i.e you have to press CTL+SHIFT+ENTER after you enter the formula

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]